Connecting a transimpedance amplifier powered by an isolated power supply to a grounded digitizer?
I've recently been assigned to a project where we are sensing changes in the current passing through a biological resistor, and these changes in current are on the order of nanoamperes and on short timescales (~10 us). You can think of it like a variable resistor. There's a small voltage applied across the resistor and chemical reactions subtly change its resistance.
To sense such small changes in current, we're using a high-gain, low-noise transimpedance amplifier (DLPCA-200); the output is then digitized by a NI-9775 and analyzed on a computer. The whole setup is in a grounded Faraday cage, vibration-isolated chassis, etc.
I'm not a professional electrical engineer; I am a biologist who dabbles in engineering. Yes, I've taken college physics and have made functional devices with Arduinos over the past few years, but I'm now working with expensive equipment and don't want to break it or proceed incorrectly and get bad measurements.
It will be some time before we're ready to test these biological resistors I mentioned above, so in the meantime I want to make a 'positive control' circuit -- in essence, I want to generate a low-current signal and ensure that I can measure it: Is the amplifier working? Can I acquire the data? How noisy is a 'perfect' signal? Etc.
I plan to generate this 'perfect' signal (probably a sine wave or square wave from 0V to 1V at 100 kHz) with an AWG (33509B) as shown in the attached schematic by placing a 1 gigaohm resistor (MOX1125-23) between the AWG output and DLPCA-200 input. The 33509B's output shield (LO) is isolated from its chassis; the maximum allowed voltage difference between the shield and chassis is 42V. The DLPCA-200's power supply is an isolated power supply (no ground prong). But: The digitizer, which connects to the output of the DLPCA-200 via a typical BNC cable, is provided power and ground via USB -> computer -> earth ground. I verified this with my multimeter. The shield of its BNC inputs is the same as the chassis of the computer it's connected to, and it's a desktop computer powered from the wall with a 3-prong plug.
That's where my bigest question comes in. Would/could there be a difference in the DLPCA-200's ground and the NI-9775's ground? Is the output of the DLPCA-200 even connected to ground via the shield of the BNC, or is it not? I'm not too sure based on the datasheet. If it is connected, would this cause issues? I've heard that isolated power supplies intentionally float and that this isolation from earth ground is important in noise-sensitive circuits. I would think that this equipment setup would be fine (i.e., that the NI-9775 and DLPCA-200 are designed for use cases like this and that isolation is maintained) but after a look through the NI-9775's datasheet, under "Isolation" it says: "Channel-to-earth-ground: NONE". There's a chassis grounding screw on the NI-9775, which I could physically connect to the chassis of the DLPCA-200 -- but would that nullify the fact that the DLPCA-200 is isolated in the first place? Would it possibly damage the DLPCA-200? Is isolation even important if all equipment are tied to the same ground, even if earth ground isn't rock-solid and fluctuates a bit? I'm in a lab and know for a fact that there are big fridges and freezers with compressors that turn on and off connected to the same power circuit as this equipment would be.
My precise questions are:
1.) Will the schematic shown allow me to generate a low-current signal I can measure with the amplifier?
2.) Is connecting an amplifier, powered by an isolated power supply, to a digitizer connected to a grounded computer, a deal breaker (or equipment breaker)?
Thank you so much for your time. This was a long post probably filled with 'silly questions' but I figure that a really clueless person would mess with expensive equipment without asking experts first.
Best,
-P23K
Edit: After discussion, and consulting with an expert on my campus, it's not an issue if I pull the DLPCA-200 to earth ground via the NI-9775 digitizer. As long as all of my equipment in my setup is referencing the same ground, and there is no ground loop, it's okay. As for the test schematic, the issue is the 1 gigaohm resistor. Though it has a small capacitance (depending on the package, femtofarads to half a picofarad), the impedance at 100 kHz is low relative to its ohmic resistance, so I would have a much larger current than 1 nA. Additionally, I won't get a square wave back; it will look more like abrupt capacitor charging and discharging. The solution is to use a lower-value resistor (100kOhm) and apply a correspondingly lower voltage signal to get a nanoamp current (so 100 uV).
Another concern is the capacitance of the cable going to the DLPCA-200. My 50 cm low-noise cable has a capacitance of 96 pF/m, so 48 pF. At this source capacitance, the DLPCA-200 has an average input noise of around 700 pA RMS. While the signal-to-noise ratio will still be more than 1, my setup would be better with an even shorter cable. I might be able to order a 10 cm cable but will try my best with the 50 cm cable for now.
I've made a voltage divider test circuit PCB and will provide an update when I start collecting data.
-P23K
Link to DLPCA-200 datasheet: https://www.femto.de/images/pdf-dokumente/de-dlpca-200.pdf
Link to NI-9775 specs: https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/ni-9775-specs/page/specs.html
Link to 33500B datasheet: https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-05928/data-sheets/5992-2572.pdf

Edits (09-23-24): I made a test circuit using a voltage divider to step down the voltage from my AWG and a 100 kOhm resistor to bring the current at the input of the DLPCA-200 to the nanoamp-microamp range. Even with a 50 cm BNC cable (~48 pF capacitance), I was able to detect a 10 kHz signal of 2 nA currents with a signal-to-noise ratio of around 2 on the DLPCA-200's low-noise setting at 10^7 V/A gain, or a 100 kHz signal of 10 nA currents with a signal-to-noise ratio of around 2 eith the DLPCA-200 set to high-speed at 10^7 V/A. I suspect I could decrease the noise by reducing the input capacitance (i.e., shorter cable). I measured the signals on an oscilloscope (I figured it would be easier to set up than the digitizer) by connecting the output of the DLPCA-200 to the oscilloscope. This pulled the ground to earth ground, and it was just fine. All equipment was connected to the same outlet.

That BNC to DLPCA-200 INPUT cable may be a problem caused by its capacitance if you're interested in sensing fast changes in current. Cable capacitance might cause your DLPCA-200 to oscillate - in any case, it will alter its frequency response. I'd want to keep it very short. You're also likely going to have to deal with ground loops that will act as antennas to local switch-mode power supplies. Your validation effort has to start somewhere...this simple setup may require lots of modification to kill the gremlins.

Thanks, @glen_geek ! The cables we'll be using are low-noise cables that have a reported capacitance around 96 pF/m, and the cable will be 0.5 m. In terms of modification of the setup, are we taking about using passive components to filter noise in certain frequency ranges, or something in that ballpark?

The amp ground and the cable shield have to be connected or no circuit exists between the amp and the A/D. Note that the load capacitance and the cable capacitance add together to form the load seen by the amp, with more capacitance degrading the effectiveness of the amp. Might be worth reaching out to the vendor and asking about capacitance, especially if your load is very low capacitance without the cable. The use of the isolated power supply should be safe, although you may not even need it.

@user1850479 Ah, silly me, I wasn't thinking when I wrote that -- of course the amplifier's ground and cable shield have to be connected for a circuit to exist! That's great advice to reach out to the manufacturer -- I'll see what they say and provide an update here! Thanks again.

@user1850479 Still waiting on reply from vendor, but in the meantime, my research has turned up 'Galvanic Isolators' for USB devices, like this one:
https://www.reichelt.com/xa/en/shop/product/usb_isolator_galvanic_isolation_host_device-116460?country=xa&CCTYPE=private&LANGUAGE=en
If I use that to connect the NI-9775 to the computer, I can then connect the chassis of the NI-9775 to the DLPCA-200 and the ground loop problem is solved, perhaps?

Why do you want a galvanic isolator for the USB?

@user1850479 The NI-9775 gets power and ground via USB, which would be connected to a desktop computer. The desktop computer is connected to earth ground via a 3-prong plug. Therefore, I'd think that the USB earth grounds the NI-9775, and because the NI-9775 is connected to the DLPCA-200, it would also earth ground the DLPCA-200, and form a ground loop. If I use a USB isolator to connect the NI-9775 to the computer, and provide aux power to the isolator with a floating power source, the NI-9775 is no longer earth grounded, and instead, the chassis of the NI-9775 can be tied to the DLPCA-200.

A ground loop is a loop passing through ground. If your PC is grounded where is the loop? Can you explain the problem you're trying to address?

@user1850479 Yeah, you're right -- I didn't explain where the other connection to ground would be. There's another connection in the final setup (not the test circuit above) that would provide a relatively low resistance path to ground (on another outlet). So, my thinking was to keep the amplifier isolated from earth ground.

Okay, figured I'd put an update here. I talked to an expert at my university and as long as there's no other low-resistance path to ground, I indeed would not need a galvanic isolator for this circuit. Even though earth ground may not be super consistent, as long as there's no ground loop and everything has the same ground, it's fine.

As for the function of the actual schematic shown here, a technician from FEMTO (the company that makes the DLPCA-200) notified me that the impedance of my gigaohm resistor is much lower than its ohmic resistance, and that as a result, it will behave more like a capacitor and I won't get my perfect square wave back at this frequency. Instead I'll get abrupt charging and discharging. So, the solution is to use a lower voltage signal (e.g., 100 uV amplitude) and use a smaller resistor such as 100kOhm. I've made a voltage divider to do this. Will provide an update when I test the circuit.
